# MySQL table format using watch

Tags: mysql, bash, unix, monitoring, watch

Currently when I run the following it doesn't output the MySQL query in the normal format:

```
cat mysqlmon.sh
mysql --raw -p"password" -D database -e "select * from table ORDER BY data_id DESC LIMIT 1;"

watch -n1 ./mysqlmon.sh
```

I've tried with and without the --raw but it always outputs with the tabbed format below:

data_id date    player_id       action  world_id        x       y       z       data
55151   2013-04-04 15:56:46     1       0       1       -360    63      -167    32

The reason for this is because I want the columns to line up due to the date one being long.

Am I missing a MySQL or watch switch from the man page?

I am also unsure of how to run watch and mysql like so (as it errors or hangs):

```
watch -n1 mysql --raw -p"password" database -e "select * from table ORDER BY data_id DESC LIMIT 1;"
watch -n1 `mysql --raw -p"password" database -e "select * from table ORDER BY data_id DESC LIMIT 1;"`
watch -n1 `mysql --raw -p"password" database -e 'select * from table ORDER BY data_id DESC LIMIT 1;'`
watch -n1 "mysql --raw -p"password" database -e 'select * from table ORDER BY data_id DESC LIMIT 1;'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use `\G` instead of `;`

example:

```
SELECT 'foo' as bar, 'meh' as moo, NOW() as date\G

-- should produce something like this:
-- ===============
-- bar:  foo
-- moo:  meh
-- date: 2013-04-06 17:05:00
```

Comment: Hmm, it likes \G as it outputs it properly. That's nicer anyway for what I want to do really as it lines it up obviously. Thanks :)